# Get the text of a html tag with dart

Tags: html, dart

I'm trying to get a text of a Small tag in HTML I get from a website with Dart. I tried few things but nothing worked.
This is what I have:

```
  List<Element> perfumes = document.getElementsByClassName('cell card fr-news-box');

  List perfumeImg = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].attributes['src']).toList();
  List perfumeLink = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].attributes['href']).toList();
  List perfumeName = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].text).toList();

  List perfumeBrand = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName(('small')[0])).toList(); //The problem is here.
```

but all I get is an empty list.

This is the relevant section of the HTML page:
[image]

My goal is to eventually make a JSON object from all of the items I get with name, brand name, img url and a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
List perfumeBrand = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('small')[0].text).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it already but this is the error I get RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Comment: try with this:   `List perfumeBrand = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('small').text).toList(); `

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this already, I get a problem with .text: The getter 'text' isn't defined for the class 'List<Element>'.

Comment: tried this before? `List perfumeBrand = perfumes.map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].text).toList();`

Comment: Yep, I got this: RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1)
I tried almost everything I found and could think of, but still nothing worked :/

Comment: could you please provide the html as well?  so can test and get to the solution.